# Symfony2 : Equivalent of flush()/perist() with DBAL

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, dbal

I am wondering if there are any equivalent to $em->persist($entity) or $em->flush() with DBAL ?

I'm meaning, how DBAL work with entity ? I'm working with entity not handled by doctrine : data to hydrate entity is retrieved with DBAL using SELECT ..., and if I have to update stuff in database, do I have to use DBAL insert()/update() functions as stated here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html ?

Do you know a simple way to record changes made to an entity while using a form ?

I hope i was understandable, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DBAL` you have no entities since this is just **D**atabase **A**bstraction **L**ayer - its responsibility is to make sure that when you run a query it will be run properly on various DB engines.

Dealing with Entities is a responsibility of **O**bject-**R**elational **M**apping library (like `DoctrineORM`).

So there is no equivalent of `flush` or `persist` in `DBAL`. To perform update on DB you need to run query like

```
$conn->executeUpdate('UPDATE user SET username = ? WHERE id = ?', array('jwage', 1))
```